# Using case add different values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There is a table named Product which contains three column- `name,id and price`.
In the below query i want to do something like If id 1,2 and 3 exist then it add id 1.id 2 and id 3's price or if only id 1 and 2 exist then it add only id 1 and id 2's price

```
select
   name,
   id,

   case 
      when id in(1,2,3) then sum(price) as total
      else ' '
   end
   case
      when id in(4,5,6) then sum (price) as total
      else ' '
   end
from
   Product
group by
   name,
   id;
```

But its not working properly.

Sample data:

```
Name ID PRICE
A     1   30
B     2   10
C     5   20
```

Expected output:

```
NAME ID TOTAL 
A    1    40
B    2    40
C    5    20
```

Comment: share some sample data and expected result

Comment: You need to remove 'price' from your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` otherwise the `SUM` basically does nothing.

Comment: But i still dnt work the way i want

Comment: What are you expecting to get and what are you actually getting?

Comment: In your expected output - is the ID for 'C' supposed to be 3 or 5?

Comment: Sorry its a mistake C=5

Comment: What database product are you using? (SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc)

Comment: i am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a unique Id, you could try `Sum() Over()`:

```
Select Name, Id, 
    Sum(Price) Over (partition by (case when id in (1,2,3) then 1 else id end)) NewPrice
From Table1
```

Results and **[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82da3/21)**:

```
| NAME | ID | NEWPRICE |
|------|----|----------|
|    A |  1 |       40 |
|    B |  2 |       40 |
|    C |  5 |       20 |
```

Comment: thank you. can you describe what is Over() done here actucally?

Comment: Sure, `Over()` clause is used to partition the data before summing them up. In addition to that, I have used a `Case expression` to group Id values (1,2,3) together.

Comment: I found your unedited answer much easier. Can you explain that one?

Comment: Both doing the same thing but my original answer used an extra Case expression. Just forget about the Case inside the Over() clause for a minute, then you will get the total of all the ids as newPrice in every row. Next step is to Group ids 1,2,3 together within the partition to get the total of grouped ids. Is it clear? Bit more about [Over() Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: Thank you but can you tell me a little bit about  **else id**  part?

Comment: Sure, Basically if ids are 1,2,3 that goes as a one partition (1) and every other id (Else Id) is a different partition with Id value.